# Google Maps Polygons shifting on dragend event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When you drag a draggable Polygon within Google Maps to a specific position without releasing the mouse button, then release the mouse button without moving the mouse further, part or all of the Polygon often shifts by a pixel.  Whether or not a shift occurs depends on some unknown combination of map zoom, polygon size, etc.  Problem is easy to reproduce - for a given Polygon, there are always multiple zoom levels for which shift occurs with *every* drop.

I'm checked with API versions 3.33-3.35 and have verified the same problem on multiple desktop browsers.  Further investigation reveals that before the dragend handler is called, a final call to the drag handler is made (regardless of whether the mouse has moved).  The latLng provided to the drag handler is *always* different from the latLng provided by the previous (real) drag event, regardless of whether a visual shift in the Polygon occurs.  Presumably the visual shift depends on some behind-the-scenes coordinate-to-pixel rounding effects.  Of course, at first I thought maybe I was actually nudging the mouse prior to releasing the drag, but I've verified that this isn't the case.

The problem can be replicated by creating any draggable Polygon and then watching carefully what happens when you drag, pause, then drop.  Here's a JSFiddle example (https://jsfiddle.net/bipwap/70vup36n) using a simple rectangle:

```
var counter = 1;

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 4,
  center: { lat: 35.0, lng: -80.0 },
  mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
  gestureHandling: 'greedy'
});

// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
var testCoords = [
  {lat: 30.0, lng: -75.0},
  {lat: 40.0, lng: -75.0},
  {lat: 40.0, lng: -85.0},
  {lat: 30.0, lng: -85.0}
];

var testPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: testCoords,
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  draggable: true,
  geodesic: false // Problem evident with or without geodesic
});
testPolygon.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(testPolygon, 'drag', function(event) {
    console.log(counter++ + " drag Lat: " + event.latLng.lat() + " Lng: " + event.latLng.lng());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(testPolygon, 'dragend', function(event) {
    console.log(counter++ + " dragend Lat: " + event.latLng.lat() + " Lng: " + event.latLng.lng());
});
```

At the default zoom, each side of the rectangular Polygon shifts when the drag ends.  At other zoom levels, none, some, or all of the sides may shift.  If you have a console window open when running the code, you can verify via diagnostic console.log() calls that (a) immediately before the dragend handler is called, the drag handler is always called and (b) the coordinates of the latLng for the drag handler in that final call are *always* different from the coordinates in the preceding drag handler call (which was associated with a true drag event).

So what's going on here?  Why is Google Maps reporting a different geographic coordinate when the drag is terminated even though the pixel coordinate of the cursor hasn't changed?

Comment: If you need an official answer, I'd suggest that you shorten your question to key facts and [open an issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:188853) about it. Link your issue and this question together.

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  I have done this (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124306181).